# (Javascript) I need to make a function that will take 180 + user inputted number \ 3 then rounded to hours and minutes

Tags: javascript, hour

Hello I'm almost finished with this assignment but I need to make a function that will take 180 + a variable divided by 3, then answer would then be outputted in hours and minutes not just minutes.

So instead of the output being 72 it would be 1 hour and 12 minutes.
This one has me stumped since the time thing is a curveball for me, any help would be appreciated!

Here's my code, I can't get it to work:

```
var pets = prompt ("How many pets do you own?");
Function GetTime() {
Math.floor(180 + pets/60) +" Hour "+ pets%60 + " Minutes.";
}
document.write GetTime;
```

Comment: I don't see you dividing the number by 3, could you explain why it needs the extra criteria? I understand wanting to convert the time, but I'm not understanding why "180 + number / 3"

Comment: I missed the divided by 3 part, i'm having trouble incorporating it into the equation. The goal is 180 + pets/3 = hours and minutes

Comment: maybe something like 180 + ((pets/3) / 60)

Comment: It's for a school assignment, I was just keeping it simple since this is a particular formula i'm stuck on. the rubric is 180 + variable/3 = X number which would then be converted to hours and minutes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First calculate the total number of minutes with `180 + pets / 3`, then calculate the number of hours with `Math.floor(totalMinutes / 60)`, and the number of remaining minutes with `totalMinutes % 60`:

```js
function length() {
  const pets = prompt("How many pets do you own?");
  const totalMinutes = 180 + pets / 3;
  const wholeHours = Math.floor(totalMinutes / 60);
  const wholeMinutes = Math.floor(totalMinutes % 60);
  console.log(wholeHours + " Hour " + wholeMinutes + " Minutes");
}
length();
```

Comment: How do I round down to the nearest minute? I'm not sure where to add math.floor again

Comment: Put it around the `wholeMinutes` expression - `Math.floor(totalMinutes % 60)`

Comment: How would I call this answer in a simple way such as naming it "Length"?

Comment: Thanks man, this is really helping me understand, i feel like im getting the basics down

Comment: You mean you want this in a function? Just put `function() { ... }` around it, give it a name of `length` if you want

Comment: it doesnt work as a function                                                 
                                                                                                        
Function length() {
const cats = prompt("What is the maximum number a cats a person should own?");
const totalMinutes = 180 + pets / 3;
const wholeHours = Math.floor(totalMinutes / 60);
const wholeMinutes = Math.floor(totalMinutes % 60);
}
document.write ("The film is " + length);

Comment: `Function` is invalid syntax (unless you're trying to invoke the `eval`-like function constructor, which shouldn't be used) - eg for a function called `length`, use `function length() {`

Comment: <script>
function length() {
const pets = prompt("What is the maximum number a cats a person should own?");
const totalMinutes = 180 + pets / 3;
const wholeHours = Math.floor(totalMinutes / 60);
const wholeMinutes = Math.floor(totalMinutes % 60);
}
document.write ("The film is " + length);
</script>

Comment: This still didnt work, it weird i cant post it as code in a reply

Comment: If you want to invoke a function, you have to put `()` at the end of the function name, like in the answer - just call `length()` and have the function do the `console.log` or the `document.write`

Comment: Odd now it just keeps saying undefined as the answer but atleast it doesn't error out it says the film is undefined:    function length() {
const pets = prompt("What is the maximum number a cats a person should own?");
const totalMinutes = 180 + pets / 3;
const wholeHours = Math.floor(totalMinutes / 60);
const wholeMinutes = Math.floor(totalMinutes % 60);
}
document.write ("The film is " + length());

Comment: Your function isn't returning anything, thus `undefined`. Either return the constructed string at the end of the function, or do the `document.write` or `console.log` inside the function, rather than outside

Answer (score 1):

let result = Math.floor(180 + pets/60) +" Hour "+ pets%60 + " Minutes.";
return new Date(result*1000).toGMTString().slice(20,25)